# Chrome print and print media emulation

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-devtools, emulation

I used to be able to use the Chrome "emulate print media" to access the features of Dev Tools. Not only has Chrome completely changed how these tools work, they don't product consistent results.

Here is a screen shot of a portion of a page in Chrome:

[image]

Here is what it looks like in the Chrome Print Preview function:

[image]

Some time ago, when faced with these issues, I was able to use Dev Tools and use styles such as -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; to get rid of the black background. Apparently, that no longer works.

But then I try to use the Chrome "Emulate print media" function, and for that page portion, I get this:

[image]

The two questions are (1) most importantly, how do I get rid of the back background when -webkit-print-color-adjust no longer seems to work; (2) why does the Chrome "Emulate print media" give such a variation from what the print preview shows?

Notes:
1. Printing to a PDF gives the same black background; printing on a printer also has the black background.
2. I have already added `* {transition:none!important}` to the print stylesheet, as suggested elsewhere.
3. The pink "Print" button downloads a nice PDF brochure, so that works fine. This question is to try to fix what happens for users who try to use the native print preview function.
4. Firefox and IE display the print version of the page as the Chrome "Emulate Print Media" does.